# How to insert values in a single table from two different source tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two different tables in my database with unique column names. I would like to add values into my new table which I have already created with column names that I need from those two tables.

> Table1: ID|CreationTime|serialNum|Caption|
>
> Table2: ID|CreationTime|Business|Case|ReportItem|

I would like to have my new tables with the following values.

> Table3: ID|CreationTime|serialNum|Business|Case|ReportItem|

I am trying to use this query which I know is not right.

```
insert into Table3([ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportingItem],[Case],[SerialNum])    
select [ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportItem],[Case]
from [Table2]     
where creationtime>='1-jan-2018' and creationtime<'2-jan-2018'

union

Select[SerialNum]    
from [Table1]     
where creationtimeutc>='1-jan-2018' and creationtime<'2-jan-2018'
```

Please help me to get it solved.

Comment: When using a UNION BOTH queries MUST have the same number and datatype for columns. Also date literal strings should be in the ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD (20180101 and 20180102 in your case). Maybe you simply need to add extra columns in your second query with NULL for the columns you don't want to provide values for?

Comment: @Solomon See my answer and for actual query. Please put sample data of both tables and expected result after insert.

Comment: @SeanLange: Yes the Creation time is in this format: 2018-11-01 12:57:27.807

Is there something i could do without adding the additional column, as i just need one column for the Table 1.

Comment: I think you should provide the sample data and expected output because it is not clear you want to update serial number or insert both table record into table 3. As in above union query serial number column is not there.

Comment: See the demo how to insert using join https://rextester.com/UOZBM85781

Answer (score 0):

You can try either Left or inner join something like this to insert data from both tables.

```
INSERT INTO user (id, name, username, opted_in)
  SELECT id, name, username, opted_in 
  FROM user LEFT JOIN user_permission AS userPerm ON user.id = userPerm.user_id
```

Here you should write the same results i.e., column and data type in all sets of union query. Here it has been described below.

Right Way

```
INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT val1, val2 
FROM TABLE1
 UNION
SELECT val1, val2
FROM TABLE2
```

Wrong Way

```
INSERT INTO #Temp1
SELECT val1, val2 
FROM TABLE1
 UNION
SELECT val2
FROM TABLE2
```

This will give error and your query will not run properly.

Comment: Hi Suraj, Thank you for your answer, but if this what u mean. 

insert into Table3([ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportingItem],[Case],[SerialNum])

select [ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportItem],[Case],[SerialNum]

from [Table2] Left join [Table1] on Table2.[ID]=Table1.[ID]

it gives me an error which says

Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'ID'.
Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Ambiguous column name 'creationtime'.

Comment: You should write tableName.Id which will not give error as it is in both table.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Table3([ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportingItem],[Case],[SerialNum])

select [ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportItem],[Case]
from [Table2] 
where creationtime>='1-jan-2018' and creationtime<'2-jan-2018'
union
Select null Id, null creationtime, null business, null reportingitem, [SerialNum]
from [Table1] 
where creationtimeutc>='1-jan-2018' and creationtime<'2-jan-2018'
```

In Union or union all need same length of columns otherwise query failed
 thank

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
insert into Table3([ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportingItem],[Case],SerialNum])select [ID],[creationtime],[Business],[ReportItem],[Case],null as [SerialNum]from [Table2] where creationtime>='1-jan-2018' and creationtime<'2-jan-2018'
union Select null as Id, null as creationtime, null as business, null as reportingitem, null as case,[SerialNum]from [Table1] where creationtimeutc>='1-jan-2018' and creationtime<'2-jan-2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
CREATE TABLE #TableOUTPUT
(
    ID int,
    creationtime datetime,
    serialNum VARCHAR(10),
    Business  varchar(10),
    [Case] varchar(10),
    ReportItem int

)
GO
CREATE TABLE TableFIRST
(
    ID int,
    creationtime datetime,
    serialNum VARCHAR(10),
    Caption varchar(10)


)
CREATE TABLE TableSECOND
(
    id int,
     creationtime datetime,
    Business varchar(10),
    [Case] varchar(10),
    ReportItem varchar(10)
)

GO
 insert into #TableOUTPUT
 SELECT T1.ID,T1.creationtime,T1.serialNum,T2.Business,T2.[Case],T2.ReportItem FROM TableFIRST T1 INNER JOIN TableSECOND T2 ON T1.ID=T2.ID 
 SELECT * FROM #TableOUTPUT
```